# Mirroring selected data from one iPad to another in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad

We have an iOS Point of Sale application where we want to show information on a customer facing iPad what is being inputted in the main iPad.

So basically we are looking to push information from one iPad to another iPad. I have seen some information about Bonjour network. Just looking for direction how to use it?

One of the things, I was thinking if we should send a push notification to 2nd iPad every time product is entered and call an web service to show the data.. It seems too much.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Bonjour is just a discover service. You can use it find ipads offering the data, but you need something else to send the data. you could write a simple system using sockets for example.

Comment: Raj, had any luck on this question?

Comment: Got it.. Let me try writing a sample to initiate the data stream from iOS device. Do I need to look for 3rd party library for socket?